# Use nmap inside my python code to get supported cipher suites

Tags: python, ssl, nmap

I'm trying to use python to list ciphers supported by a server i.e google.com. I stumbled upon [this](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers) and I'm particularly interested with the second answer regarding `nmap`. The only problem is that I can only figure out how to run nmap in the command line (because the answer tells you exactly how to do it). Is there a way I can get this to run in python code and have that same output return in a json format or anything else simple enough to parse?

I've looked into [python-nmap](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) but I don't see an option for doing what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Basically you asked how to execute a command (in this case nmap) and capture the output. Therefore marked as duplicate of existing questions. As for parsing the output - stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Try first by your own.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Basically that's not what I asked...I got a good answer here: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Use-nmap-inside-my-python-code-to-get-supported-cipher-suites?marksolved=1